# Angular Material dialog: why make it so complicated?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, primeng

I've been working with Angular and Angular Material for a while. One thing that bewilders me is how much boiler plate code you need write to just create a simple dialog.

The dialog needs to be defined in a component, and adds to the entry declaration of the module if not used in the same file. The dialog itself needs to inject a MatDialogRef, so you can pass data out when it closes. You need to inject a MatDialog into the main component that opens the dialog. You need to call its open function to open the dialog and pass value explicitly to the component. You probably need to read a tutorial to start using it.

It works well but compared with other implementations, it just seems too complicated. For example, in PrimeNG, a component library for Angular, you can define a dialog like:

```
<p-dialog header="Title" [(visible)]="display">
    Content
</p-dialog>
```

You have a single variable that controls the visibility of the dialog. Anyone knows a little Angular can start using it with no learning curve.

So my question is: why Angular material wants to implement this way? What kind of advantage does it have? Is it efficiency or it gives you more flexibility in implementing complex functionalities?

Comment: Flexibility for more complex cases. In cases where dialogs are more complicated and have they own state, not being able to _decouple_ them from the client component would be a mess.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit? PrimeNG's dialog can also be defined in a separate component and thus can be decoupled.

Comment: I completely agree with you, Angular Material is overengineered (as Angular it self), trying to solve not existing issues. The complexity doesn't add anything to its reusability or scalability.